# Ubuntu Docker container immediately stops, issue with Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm pretty new to Docker, and completely baffled as to why my container exits upon start.

I've built an Ubuntu image of which starts Apache and fail2ban upon boot. I'm unsure as to whether it's an issue with the Dockerfile, or the command I am running to start the container.

I've tried:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 image
docker run -d -ti -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 image
docker run -d -ti -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 image /bin/bash
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y iptables && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y apache2 fail2ban && \
  rm -rf /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

ADD index.html /var/www/html/
ADD jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/

ENV  HOME /root
WORKDIR /root

EXPOSE 80 443

ENTRYPOINT service apache2 start && service fail2ban start
CMD ["bash"]
```

I can jump into the container itself with:

```
docker exec -it image /bin/bash
```

But the moment I try to run it whilst staying within the host, it fails. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Considering your question, where you mention "upon boot" I think it would be useful to read https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/.

In a nutshell docker containers do not "boot" as a normal system, they start a process and execute it until it exits.

So, if you want to start two processes you can do a wrapper script as explained at the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following line from your Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["bash"]
```

Also, when you want to get a shell into your container, you have to override the `ENTRYPOINT` definition of your Dockerfile:

```
docker exec -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" image
```

See [Dockerfile "ENTRYPOINT" documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) for more details

Comment: I tend to avoid ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfiles, unless it’s a script that ends in `exec "$@"`, for exactly this reason.